# Bloom filter - using the number of elements as the number of hash functions

Tags: hash, big-o, time-complexity, probability, bloom-filter

my question is, if we use k (number of hash functions) as n (the number of elements to be inserted), I saw that the probability of getting false positive is extremely low. I realize this is really slow..is this the worst case? And will this ensure that a false positive is never made?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can never ensure that a Bloom filter has no false positives by changing the number of hash functions. [The optimal number of hash functions is linear in the ratio of the space to the cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Optimal_number_of_hash_functions), so your choice will be quite far from optimal unless you use so much space that you might as well store the set directly, avoiding the Bloom filter altogether.

This last part is not true if your objects are truly enormous or you have a tiny number of them.